# Dissolving streets by distance using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Is there any way to dissolve a streets network to districts based on a distance given?

The streets of the districts must have the same sum of the  distance.

example:

The selected districts should look like the one in blue, the sum of the streets in this district is 2 km

[image: The selected districts should look like the one in blue, the sum of the streets in this district is 2 km]

Comment: As in "divide network into equal parts based on length"?

Comment: Also, please decide on a software you want to use.

Comment: Yes exactly "divide network into equal parts based on length" and for the software, i can use both Qgis or Arcgis

Comment: You must choose *one* software stack for this question due to our One question per Question policy (as articulated in the [Tour]).

Comment: OK, so I chose Arcgis,

Comment: Also, choosing the software simply allows for easier answering. If you ask for two softwares and get an answer for each of them... how do you choose, which is the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, I get you .. I didn't choose the software because the important for me is to find the solution

Comment: This is a routing problem as in it will require a topology to figure this out. Are you able to use PostGIS + pgRouting @Adam?

Comment: Yes, what do you propose as a solution?

Comment: Using pgRouting you will be able to build a topology of the input streets. The rough idea is as follows: using an arbitrary seed street you will have to compute isochrones / reachability with a cutoff - something similar as described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325138/performing-isochrone-in-postgis-by-pgrouting . Sum up all streets in that reachability area until the threshold of 2 km is reached. These are then removed from the topology as they create a district. Continue until all streets have been added to a district.